# Are tag badges given according to upvotes or score?

Tags: discussion, bug, tag-badges

When I was looking at badges I realized there were two different explanations on how to get the tag badges.

[image: tag badge page]

I thought:

```
score = nUpvotes - nDownvotes;
```

Is this correct? If it is, do I need to have 100 upvotes for a bronze badge, or do I need a score of 100?

Comment: Shouldn't it be fixed? Looks like it is an issue since Sep 2010 as @AakashM said.

Comment: We have bugs even older than that. The dev team has its own list and its own priorities, all we can do is report.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd does this count as reporting?

Comment: @HebeleHododo: Only if you tag it as [bug] ;) Anyway, this was already reported, so I'm going to mark it as a dupe.

Comment: As mortal users most we can do to bump a bug report is start a bounty on it. I've just done that now on that old report.